# Showing positive stability of a matrix constructed from a positive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, nonnegative-matrices, stability

A is a positive nonsingular matrix. Let $s>\rho(A)$. We want to show that $B\equiv\left(A^{T}A\right)^{-1}\left(sI-A^{T}\right)$ is a positive stable matrix, i.e., all eigenvalues of this matrix have a positive real part.

$\textbf{Some Thoughts}$: Suppose that $A$ is diagonalizable, and let $D_{A}$ be a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of $A$ on the diagonal. Let $S$ be the matrix with eigenvectors of $A$ as columns, i.e., $S=\left[x_{1},\dots,x_{N}\right]$ and $x_{i}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for each $i$. Then 
$A=SD_{A}S^{-1}$ and so we have $B=\left[A^{T}A\right]^{-1}\left(sI-A^{T}\right) =\left[S^{-T}D_{A}S^{T}SD_{A}S^{-1}\right]^{-1}\left(sI-S^{-T}D_{A}S^{T}\right)
 =SD_{A}^{-1}\left(S^{T}S\right)^{-1}D_{A}^{-1}\left(sI-D_{A}\right)S^{T}.$

Matrix $\left[SD_{A}^{-1}\left(S^{T}S\right)^{-1}D_{A}^{-1}\left(sI-D_{A}\right)S^{T}\right]$ has the same eigenvalues as $C\equiv\left[\left(S^{T}S\right)D_{A}^{-1}\left(S^{T}S\right)^{-1}D_{A}^{-1}\left(sI-D_{A}\right)\right]$

Matrix $C$ is a product of a positive definite matrix $\left(S^{T}S\right)$ with another positive definite matrix $D_{A}^{-1}\left(S^{T}S\right)^{-1}D_{A}^{-1}$  and a diagonal matrix $\left(sI-D_{A}\right)$. This looks quite nice. Of course, this structure generally does not result in a positive stable matrix. Namely, if we randomly generate a positive diagonal matrix $D_{A}$ and a non-singular matrix $S$, then the matrix with the structure of $C$ generally is not positive stable. Somehow, it is important that $S$ is a matrix of eigenvectors of a positive matrix.

Note that $B^{-1}$ is a positive matrix. So, $B$ is like an $M$-matrix. But, of course, generally $B$ is not an $M$-matrix. Also, in case of $N=2$: (i) $\left[A^{T}A\right]^{-1}$ is a $Z$-matrix and, hence, $B$ is also a $Z$-matrix; (ii) $\det(B)>0$ (in fact, $\det\left(B\right)>0$ for any $N$); (iii) Since, $B$ is a $Z$-matrix, its principal minors of size $1$ (which are the diagonal elements of $B$) are positive. Hence, for $N=2$, $B$ is an $M$-matrix.

$\textbf{Note that}$: $Z$-matrices are those matrices whose off-diagonal entries are less than or equal to zero; that is, a $Z$-matrix $Z$ satisfies $Z=(z_{ij})$;$\quad z_{ij}\leq 0$, $\quad i\neq j$.

An M-matrix is commonly defined as follows:
Let $A$ be a $n × n$ real $Z$-matrix. Then matrix $A$ is also an $M$-matrix if it can be expressed in the form $A = sI - B$, where $B$ is a positive matrix, $s$ is greater than the maximum of the moduli of the eigenvalues of $B$, and $I$ is an identity matrix.

Comment: I don't understand the stable homotopy tag.

Comment: What are $M$- and $Z$-matrices? Does stable mean "all eigenvalues have modulus less than 1"? And is your question to show that $B$ is positive and stable?

Comment: Thanks Steve. I added some clarification on these things.

Comment: It was a mistake Sean. I took off that tag.

Comment: Do you have ample numerical evidence that this is true? Have you done at least 1000 experiments with random-generated matrices and $s$ very close to $\rho(A)$, for instance?

Comment: Yes Federico and we have not been able to find a counter example.

Comment: So far we have been able to show that the statement is true if matrix $A$ is normal or doubly stochastic.